# Memory error when try to find the longest substring that is the same in reverse in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, nsmutablestring

I got below memory error when I try to find the longest substring that is the same in reverse. The app crashes after eat all of the computers memory.

> mach_vm_map(size=1048576) failed (error code=3)
>   *** error: can't allocate region securely

I call the function from viewDidLoad with the string and my codes are also below. Thanks for any help.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *text = @"FourscoreandsevenyearsagoourfaathersbroughtforthonthiscontainentanewnationconceivedinzLibertyanddedicatedtothepropositionthatallmenarecreatedequalNowweareengagedinagreahtcivilwartestingwhetherthatnaptionoranynartionsoconceivedandsodedicatedcanlongendureWeareqmetonagreatbattlefiemldoftzhatwarWehavecometodedicpateaportionofthatfieldasafinalrestingplaceforthosewhoheregavetheirlivesthatthatnationmightliveItisaltogetherfangandproperthatweshoulddothisButinalargersensewecannotdedicatewecannotconsecratewecannothallowthisgroundThebravelmenlivinganddeadwhostruggledherehaveconsecrateditfaraboveourpoorponwertoaddordetractTgheworldadswfilllittlenotlenorlongrememberwhatwesayherebutitcanneverforgetwhattheydidhereItisforusthelivingrathertobededicatedheretotheulnfinishedworkwhichtheywhofoughtherehavethusfarsonoblyadvancedItisratherforustobeherededicatedtothegreattdafskremainingbeforeusthatfromthesehonoreddeadwetakeincreaseddevotiontothatcauseforwhichtheygavethelastpfullmeasureofdevotionthatweherehighlyresolvethatthesedeadshallnothavediedinvainthatthisnationunsderGodshallhaveanewbirthoffreedomandthatgovernmentofthepeoplebythepeopleforthepeopleshallnotperishfromtheearth";

    [self findTheLongestReverse:text];
}

- (BOOL)findTheLongestReverse:(NSString *)str
{
    NSInteger txtIndex = [str length];
    int k, i;

    for(k = 0; k < (txtIndex +1); k++) {
        for (i = 0; i < (k + 1); i++) {
            NSRange subStrRange = NSMakeRange(i, txtIndex - k);

            NSString *subString = [str substringWithRange:subStrRange];

            NSInteger charIndex = [subString length];
            NSMutableString *reversedString = [NSMutableString string];
            while (charIndex > 0) {
                charIndex--;
                NSRange subStrRange2 = NSMakeRange(charIndex, 1);

                [reversedString appendString:[subString substringWithRange:subStrRange2]];
            }

            if([subString isEqualToString:reversedString]) {
                NSLog(@"reverse word is: %@", subString);
                return YES;
            }

        }

    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "longest substring that is the same in reverse"? You mean some string of characters within a larger string that is a palindrome? Like "This is my dad" contains "dad"? or "ma am I your favorite" contains "ma am"?

Comment: if the input was "Ilikeracecarsthatgofastblabladadblabla"  the answer would be "racecar". Because "racecar" is same on reverse and longest than "dad" or "ma am".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a horribly inefficient algorithm both in terms of time and memory required. For a string of length n you are going to do n squared passes through the inner for loop, creating at least 3 temporary strings each time. Then you have a while loop inside that, creating another temporary string for each pass through that while loop.  I'd have to do some more analysis, but this might even be an n cubed algorithm, which is truly dreadful.

Temporary objects accumulate in memory until the current autorelease pool is drained. Usually that's when your method returns.

You can fix the memory problem by enclosing the entire contents of your inner for loop in an

```
@autoreleasepool
{
}
```

block. That will cause all auto release objects that are created inside the braces to be released every time your code exits the braces. So every time you leave your inner for loop, the multiple temporary string objects you've created will be released. This won't make your algorithm any more efficient, but it should prevent you from crashing due to memory pressure..

Edit:

Rather than building tons of temporary strings and using string searching, this problem would probably be best suited for simpler code.

Loop through the string fetching one character at a time using the method characterAtIndex, and compare the current character to other characters also using characterAtIndex. I'd have to sit down with pencil and paper for a few minutes to design an algorithm, but it should be straightforward to write a method that finds the largest palindrome in a string without creating ANY temporary strings.

Comment: Hi Duncan, as you suggest it worked correctly when I put inner loop in @autorelaisepool block. But still takes to much time. I'll try to find a better algorithm. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Does your program work correctly (if inefficiently) for shorter strings?

Does it work correctly if there are **no** substrings at all that are the same in reverse?

Does it work correctly for a simple, really obvious substring such as "ee"?

Does it work for zero-length strings - "" - one-letter strings - "x" - as well as strings with odd and even numbers of letters?

Duncan C is correct, you're allocating too much memory because of the inefficiency of your algorithm.  However, before choosing a more-efficient algorithm, determine whether the - inefficient - algorithm you've already got is at least correct, if memory-hungry.

This will help you understand your problem, and your solution better.

At that point, try to find a better algorithm.

If you really don't know how to find a better algorithm, I suggest you read Robert Sedgewick's "Algorithms".  I favor his second edition, with the algorithms given in pascal.  It can be had used for eight bucks.

However be advised that most algorithms texts consider only runtime but not memory.  In general but not always a fast algorithm won't use any more memory than the input and "a little bit extra".  But there are some algorithms such as lookup tables - or precomputed tables - where one can gain a great deal of speed, but at the cost of using lots of memory.

Allocation takes time, for many reasons - you have to call the allocator, it has to find a free block that is big enough, you'll be thrashing the data cache, there may be more code than an algorithm that doesn't allocate so much, you'll be paging if your code runs on a desktop or server OS (but not mobile, they don't generally use backing store).

Comment: Hi Michael, yes the program works correctly if I use less letters, for example about 800 letters, it takes long but does work without crashing. And or the book advice, as you can see I really need to read something about algorithms. Thanks for comment and book advice.